# Roo cannot display spreadsheet, method unfound

Tags: ruby, ruby-roo

I am using [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) and would like to preview a spreadsheet by following the document says:
`<%= spreadsheet @rspreadsheet, ["Tabelle"] %>`
But the error says 
"undefined method `spreadsheet' " I don't know if i missed any gem.

BTW, I've added the 'spreadsheet' gem, while i feel it it nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Did you add `require 'roo'` in the beginning of you script?

Comment: I add gem 'roo' in my Rails Gemfile

Comment: That's a different thing. You have to `require` file for working with it.

Comment: After adding `require 'roo'` in controller, still not work

Comment: You use `spreadsheet` in you view, you shouldn't require it in your controller. Try to add `<% require 'roo' %>` in the beginning of you view.

Answer (score 2):

Roo doesn't seem to require the rails helper module.

```
require 'roo/roo_rails_helper'
```

in the controller works for me.

If you use Rails 3, you need to write

```
<%= raw spreadsheet @rspreadsheet, ["Tabelle"] %>
```

in the view.